# Refresh the user's data

Tags: android, deezer

Is there any way to refresh user's data after logged in ?

I've successfully done my login, I can retrieve the new information about my user using `mDeezerConnect.requestAsync(DeezerRequestFactory.requestCurrentUser(),...)` but my `mDeezerConnect.getCurrentUser()` stays with the same information...

Answer (score -1):

Create a getter-setter method and put values from server over there and get it by calling getter and use the info in your app.
Hope it helps ;-)